# PHP: The name of the previous method in chain

Tags: php, method-chaining

I am method chaining in PHP, something like this:

```
$c = new someClass();

$c->blackMethod()->colourMethod();
$c->whiteMethod()->colourMethod();
```

Is there any way the colourMethod() can know if it was called after the blackMethod() or whiteMethod()? In other words, is there a way of getting the name of the previously called method in a chain of methods?

Something like this:

```
$c->blackMethod()->colourMethod();
//output: "The colour is black";

$c->whiteMethod()->colourMethod();
//output: "The colour is white";
```

I understand that chaining is only shorthand for calling multiple methods from the same class, but I was hoping there is a way to link the chains together somehow.

I have tried debug_backtrace() and

```
$e = new Exception();
$trace = $e->getTrace();
```

but they only give class names or the name of the method that called the colourMethod (which is $c), not the method that was called before it.

Comment: `blackMethod` should set some state on the object (a property, etc), which `colourMethod` can then refer to. Whatever you do, don't use a backtrace.

Comment: I'm curious - why do you need that? I smell a gun pointed at your own foot :)

Comment: Agree, even with the example it does not seem to make the most sense. You expect a “the color _is_ …” output - but why _is_ it, actually? If `blackMethod` or `whiteMethod` did not set anything anywhere, then where would any color “be” in the first place?

Comment: CBroe, you raise an interesting point. I am still curious if it's possible to get the name though.

Comment: A class method knows two things - the state of its instance, and any input parameters. You can refactor the code to stop using a fluent interface (`$c->colourMethod('black')`), or use the class's state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good and more general way  to get a track of the previously called method is to use a private or protected property to keep track of the actual method using the constante `__FUNCTION__` or `__METHOD__` 

example:

```
   class colorchanger
    {
    protected prevMethod;
    public function black() 
    { 
    /*
    your routine
    for the black 
    method here
    */
    $this->prevMethod =__FUNCTION__;
    return $this;
    }

    public function white()
    { 
    /*
     your routine
    for the white
    method here
    */
    $this->prevMethod =__FUNCTION__;
    return $this;
    }

    public function colour() 
    {
    return $this->prevMethod;
    }

    }

$c = new ColorChanger();
$c->black->colour();
$c->white()->colour();
$c->black()->white->colourMethod();//will return white instead of black
```

Comment: This is still essentially storing the state, via each of the methods. He posted a reply to my comment: "So there is no way of "looking back" without storing a value when running the previous method?", which your answer seems to lack

Comment: the only way to keep track is effectively to save the current state and i don't deny.But my suggestion is to keep track automatically of the current method name  using the appropriate constante,instead of write it manually each time.It is more generic I think and can be used in any project.

Comment: I was really hoping for a way to avoid having to manually keep track, but if that's the only way, then your generic method may be the easiest way of implementing it. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just set a property on the object:

```
<?php

class ColorChanger
{
    private $lastColor;

    public function blackMethod() {
        echo "blackMethod(); Last color: {$this->lastColor}\n";
        $this->lastColor = 'black';
        return $this;
    }

    public function whiteMethod() {
        echo "whiteMethod(); Last color: {$this->lastColor}\n";
        $this->lastColor = 'white';
        return $this;
    }

    public function colourMethod() {
        echo "colourMethod(): {$this->lastColor}\n";
        $this->lastColor = null;
    }
}

$c = new ColorChanger();

$c->blackMethod()->colourMethod();
$c->whiteMethod()->colourMethod();

$c->blackMethod()->whiteMethod()->colourMethod();
```

Example [here](https://3v4l.org/Pe158).

If you need to get a history, [use an array](https://3v4l.org/hKiu6):

```
<?php

class ColorChanger
{
    public $lastColors = [];

    public function blackMethod() {
        $colors = implode(', ', $this->lastColors);
        echo "blackMethod(); Last colors: {$colors}\n";
        $this->lastColors[] = 'black';
        return $this;
    }

    public function whiteMethod() {
        $colors = implode(', ', $this->lastColors);
        echo "whiteMethod(); Last colors: {$colors}\n";
        $this->lastColors[] = 'white';
        return $this;
    }

    public function colourMethod() {
        $colors = implode(', ', $this->lastColors);
        $lastColor = $this->lastColors[count($this->lastColors)-1];
        echo "colourMethod(): {$colors} (Last: $lastColor)\n";
        $this->lastColors = [];
    }
}

$c = new ColorChanger();

$c->blackMethod()->colourMethod();
$c->whiteMethod()->colourMethod();

$c->blackMethod()->whiteMethod()->blackMethod()->colourMethod();
```

Comment: Franker, thanks for the prompt reply. So there is no way of "looking back" without storing a value when running the previous method?

Comment: @dearsina Check out [this](https://3v4l.org/lXp0I) example (Although, I wouldn't recommend due to performance/losing the ability to have public/private methods without even more magic). The best way is to store the previous state in some private variable in the class, before you return `$this` and chain to the next method. You could create a simple `$this->log()` function that logs the current method call, as well as any arguments that were passed.